# How to format date in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, date

I have a simple issue. This is my startDate:

```
$scope.startDate = new Date();
```

I need the date in "2011-01-01T00:00:00" this format.

Comment: So...what libraries are you using in your application, if any?  Are you doing this via filters in the DOM (not the best idea) or are you doing this in a controller?  Where have you managed to get and where are you stuck?

Comment: this is in my controller. I need to pass the value in my post data.

Comment: Can't you just convert the date to the required format server side? When you are 'post'ing the data. Share some code for us to see how you handle the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested use the $filter built-in service, by passing in to your controller:

```
angular.module('app')
       .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyService', '$filter', function($scope, MyService, $filter) {
            $scope.onSubmit = onSubmit;

            function OnSubmit() {
                MyService.doSomethingSpecial($filter('date')($scope.date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')); // see supported formats
            }

       });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about displaying your date in Angular, you can use the [**date filter**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):

```
{{startDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}
```

Answer (score -3):

Did you try using [angular date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):
It has support to specify timezone too.